# Assembler x64 Nasm single string concatenation

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm new in assembler and try to performer some simple task, like enter name and get 'Hey name' answer. Sofar I read input and assign it to my undeclared variable than put this variable into rdx register and show it on the display. The problem is that I have no idea how to put tekst2 variable to rdx not replacing tekst;

```
  section .text

    section .data
tekst db "Hey ", 0ah

global _start
_start:

;read input
mov rax,0 ;numer funkcji sys_read
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,tekst2
mov rdx, 20
syscall
;move input to rbx for later compare
mov rbx,tekst
mov rbx,tekst2

;print
mov rax, 1 
mov rdi, 1 
mov rsi, rbx
mov rdx, 20
syscall
mov rax, 60
syscall

section .bss
tekst2: resw 1
```

Comment: How could you do this in C, given a function that prints strings which you do know how to use?

Comment: I have never use C

Comment: Well how would you do it in any other programming language that you know?  e.g. print strings separately, or concatenate them into one string, right?

Comment: Yea, I would take input and add it to string variable that have first part 'variable +=input' or create 1 more variable that will contain variable + input value

Comment: So reserve space and write a loop that copies both strings into another buffer.  Or sys_read into a buffer big enough to append the other string without copying first.  Or like I said, just print both strings separately with two calls to sys_write.

Comment: So in assembler string compare is possible only by using loop?
If yes, I'll be grateful for some simple example

Comment: What do you mean "compare"?  I thought you wanted to print both strings, not test if they were equal.

Comment: Oh sorry wrong word. I mean string concatenation

Comment: So, what did you think the high level languages are doing internally, magic? Anyway, if you are so new to programming, that you don't know how strings are stored in memory*, work with numbers only first. You don't need to do any strings in the beginning, check number values in debugger in registers window. (*: your `tekst2: resw 1` reserves 2 bytes in memory, which is enough for 2 letters in ASCII encoding, while you do syscall with 20 length parameter, so user entering 3+ chars will overwrite some memory beyond `tekst2`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an assignment and the scope is to display `Hey "entry"`, this snipped formats output to have a single line below command prompt and another above the next.

```
            section .data
  Prompt:   db  10, 9, 'Hey '    
    Ends:   db  10

            section .bss
   Entry:   resb    80

            section .text
    global  _start

   _start:  mov     eax, 1                  ; SYS_WRITE
            mov     edi, eax                ; STDOUT
            mov     esi, Prompt
            mov     edx, Ends - Prompt
            push    rax                     ; We'll need these later to display
            push    rax                     ; another line feed after entry
            syscall             
            push    rsi                     ; Points to Ends, needed later

    ; Get input

            mov      al, 0
            mov     edi, eax
            mov     esi, Entry
            mov      dl, 80
            syscall

    ; Finally display string @ Ends

            pop     rsi                 ; Points to Ends
            pop     rdi                 ; STDOUT
            pop     rax                 ; SYS_WRITE
            mov      dl, 1
            syscall

            xor     rdi, rdi            ; Return code from prologue
            mov     eax, 60
            syscall
```

Technically, the strings are concatenated, just that it's done in video memory.

Another version is that you could do an implicit concatenation by declaring `Entry` immediately after `Prompt`,

```
          section .data
  Prompt:   db  10, 9, 'Hey '    
   Entry:   times 80 db 10
```

then after your input, simply add 6 to the value that's already in AL, move it to DL and display Prompt & Entry as one, achieving the same result as the previous example. Everything you need is in attached code, all that's required is to delete 5 lines, move 5 lines and change 3 parameters and the new declaration in `.data` will work.